# mongodb all data is stored to one shard

Tags: mongodb, sharding

I am trying to setup shard with one config server, one router and 2 sards with one node each. However, all data is directed to on shard only.
Below are the steps I am following.

```
mongod --port 27019 --configsvr --dbpath "config server db path" --replSet rs01
    rs.initiate(
        {
            _id: "rs01",
            configsvr: true,
            members: [
                { _id: 0, host : "localhost:27019" }
            ]
        }
    )

mongod --config "path\mongod.cfg" --shardsvr --replSet rs02
    rs.initiate(
        {
            _id: "rs02",
            members: [
                { _id: 0, host : "localhost:27040" }
            ]
        }
    )
mongod --config "path\mongod.cfg" --shardsvr --replSet rs03
    rs.initiate(
        {
            _id: "rs03",
            members: [
                { _id: 0, host : "localhost:27041" }
            ]
        }
    )
mongos --configdb rs01/localhost:27019
sh.addShard( "rs02/localhost:27040")
sh.addShard( "rs03/localhost:27041")
sh.enableSharding("social")
```

Until here there is no collection or data
This is the expected data in "inbox" collection of "social" database.

```
{
    "to": ["a", "b"],
    "from": 12,
    "message": "hello world"
}
```

After this I am executing below code from nodejs code connecting to router server

1. Created index on "from" field of "inbox" collection
2. Created shard key on "from" field of "inbox" collection

Below is the result of shard status

```
--- Sharding Status ---
  sharding version: {
        "_id" : 1,
        "minCompatibleVersion" : 5,
        "currentVersion" : 6,
        "clusterId" : ObjectId("5f95862f3eef5ee1bb33a6a3")
  }
  shards:
        {  "_id" : "rs02",  "host" : "rs02/localhost:27040",  "state" : 1 }
        {  "_id" : "rs03",  "host" : "rs03/localhost:27041",  "state" : 1 }
  active mongoses:
        "4.2.2" : 1
  autosplit:
        Currently enabled: yes
  balancer:
        Currently enabled:  yes
        Currently running:  no
        Failed balancer rounds in last 5 attempts:  0
        Migration Results for the last 24 hours:
                No recent migrations
  databases:
        {  "_id" : "config",  "primary" : "config",  "partitioned" : true }
        {  "_id" : "social",  "primary" : "rs02",  "partitioned" : true,  "version" : {  "uuid" : UUID("6d3b8ab0-fbd0-42a0-b911-1498a2244ce1"),  "lastMod" : 1 } }
                social.inbox
                        shard key: { "from" : 1 }
                        unique: false
                        balancing: true
                        chunks:
                                rs02    1
                        { "from" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } -->> { "from" : { "$maxKey" : 1 } } on : rs02 Timestamp(1, 0)
```

Here minKey and maxKey is 1 and all data is getting saved in primary(rs02) shard without splitting to another shard(rs03), I even tired inserting more than 1000 documents. In addition, I have reduced chunk size to 1MB
Below is the result of db.getCollection('inbox').getShardDistribution()

```
Shard rs02 at rs02/localhost:27040
 data : 100KiB docs : 51 chunks : 1
 estimated data per chunk : 100KiB
 estimated docs per chunk : 51

Totals
 data : 100KiB docs : 51 chunks : 1
 Shard rs02 contains 100% data, 100% docs in cluster, avg obj size on shard : 1KiB
```

Comment: How many different values do you have for `from`? When you have a new database then you have to wait some time. It takes a while till the balancer distributed all data across the shards.

Comment: When you have only 1000 documents then MongoDB will not distribute them. Insert a Million to get them sharded.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit "from" field has only positive integer values

Comment: Can you post the command you used to create shard key?